# How to use NSArray predicate in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, nsarray

I am having **NSArray** with some objects.

example:

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"one",@"two",@"four",@"five",@"one",nil];
```

in the above array , object `@"one"` occurred 3 times.If I predicate or filter that object. it has to display only one time with all remaining objects in a new array.

expected output:

```
(one , two, three, two, four, five).
```

Comment: Please use proper English not "txt spk" when asking questions. It makes it easier for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use `NSSet` not `NSArray`.

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"one",@"two",@"four",@"five",@"one"];

NSSet *uniqueObjectSet = [NSSet setWithArray:objects];
```

`uniqueObjectSet` will now contain each unique value only once.

You can go back to an array...

```
NSArray *uniqueObjectArray = [uniqueObjectSet allObjects];
```